# Unable to use parent module classes in child module in java

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I  have a project where all features are in module manner. So in that I have 2 modules, one is core and another one is imageprocess. So `Imageprocess` added core as a dependency. Now I want to use `Imageprocesser` module class in core module. When I added this `Imageprocess` as a dependency my build got failed and getting *cyclic error*.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven cyclic dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818497/maven-cyclic-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

You can only have dependencies in one direction.

Either `imageprocess` depends on `core` or the other way round. Not both.

If there are classes you need in both modules, you need to move them or introduce a third module (maybe `base`) that is used as dependency in both `imageprocess` and  `core`.